# How to apply gamma node to image

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, color

Is there a way to apply a gamma node to the image file, like how you can apply a modifier to a mesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do that in the compositor. Add the *Gamma* node in there and render the image to apply the gamma.